# Persitant/static login credentials in android app?

Tags: java, android

Android devices list different login credentials in the settings under "accounts". How do I get my app to save the user login credentials there or utilize that function in my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you would use `AccountManager` along with your implementations of `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` and `AccountAuthenticatorActivity`.

Disclaimer: I do not recommend attempting this if you are a beginning Android programmer.

This is the best article on the internet for using `AccountManager` with custom accounts and authentication:  [Write your own Android Authenticator](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/)

Answer (score 0):

The [Android documentation](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html) has some good training articles about how to do this. I'd recommend you check them out.

Basically, you need to implement a custom `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` that provides your authentication logic, specify the authenticator service in your manifest, and then you will be able to provide accounts and authentication through the system UI.